# Separate particular word from string

Tags: java, android

I have One String 
which has value

```
String someString = "/category/subcategory/Fruit/apple/";
```

I want to separate "Fruit" from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `Array` of `Strings` by splitting with `/` character like:

```
String[] split = someString.split("/");
```

This Array `split[]` has all the elements separated. You can use whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values = someString.split("/");
Log.i(TAG, values[3]);
```

Comment: I think `values[3]` will give "Fruit" as output. Because String starts with `/`

Comment: fixed! Thank You.